# Xcode Adding a ViewController To Tap bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I am creating a Tapped application and at the moment i have to `ViewControllers` but i would like four but I'm not sure how to add a `ViewController` to the Tapped application  i have added two in to the design. Its just how do i connect then with a tapped bar `ViewControler`

Thanks Very Much In Advanced.

Comment: Dear! are you talking about `tab bar application`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]If I am not misunderstood, then you want to add two more viewcontroller in your tabbed application.If you are using nib. then just drag two tab bar item into xib and in property under custom class section in class tag provide the viewcontroller name which you want to display.